# how to define href dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, href

I'm trying to make a gallery with highslide.

I have two thumbnails, a larger but cropped one listed on the page opening the large image if clicked on, and a smaller one with varying aspect ratio for the thumbstrip.

How do I configure highslide to actually use different images for the thumbstrip?

For example this is a part

```
<a href="picture12.jpg" class="highslide" 
        title="Caption from the anchor's title attribute" 
        onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    <img src="picture12.thumb.jpg"  alt=""/>
</a>
```

if i am defining href on .aspx.cs page the onclick event is not working.?

```
<a  class='highslide' id="thumb1" runat="server" href="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)" title="Two cabins" >
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  BorderWidth="2px"  />
</a>
```

aspx.cs

even if i am defining onclick event on .cs page its still not working

```
thumb1.HRef = s1;

 thumb1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)");
```

plz help m to fix this prob??

Comment: Tag this question properly, this seems like and asp.net related question

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery, put your thumb1 into a div and add onclick jquery script to it to changes images and styles.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#hrefDiv').click(function () {
            /*change href's and sizes here */
        });
    });
    </script>
```